# Why can't I get the index of this li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long list and need to get the index of every li within it.  Here's my html:

```
 <ul id="myUl" class="playlist playlist-one cf">

   <li id="test"><a href="#during-your-stay" class="playlist-link" >1.  Privacy &amp; Dignity for all</a>[00:34]</li>
   <li><a href="#during-your-stay" class="playlist-link" >2.  Medicines</a>[00:44]</li>
   <li><a href="#during-your-stay" class="playlist-link" >3.  Allergies</a>[00:25]</li>

</ul>
```

My jquery:

```
$(".playlist-link").click(function(){

    var thisLi=$(this).parent();
    var theUl= $(thisLi).parent();
    var index =theUl.index(thisLi);

    alert("ul id: " + theUl.attr('id') +"\n the li: " + thisLi.attr('id') +"\n index: "+index +"\n" )



});
```

My alert shows my index isn't working as it returns -1.  However I have the syntax correct (i think) becase the variables are using contain the right elements.  Here is output of the alert:

```
 ul id: myUl
 the li: test
 index: -1
```

So why is it returning -1???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`index()` returns the index of an element within a set of elements, not within the children of the first element in the set.

Your `theUl` variable contains exactly one element – the `<ul>` tag.  Since this set doesn't have your `<li>` tag, `index()` returns `-1`.

You can write `theUl.children().index(thisLi)` to find the index of the `<li>` in the `<ul>`'s children.

You can also just write `thisLi.index()` to return the index of the `<li>` within it's immediate parent.

http://api.jquery.com/index